# NSRegularExpression and capture groups on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex, mediawiki

I need a little kickstart on regex on the iphone.
Basically I have a list of dates in a private MediaWiki in the form of
`*185 BC: SOME EVENT HERE`
`*2001: SOME OTHER EVENT MUCH LATER`

I now want to parse that into an Object that has a NSDate property and a -say- NSString property.
I have this so far: (rawContentString contains the mediawiki syntax of the page)

```
NSString* regexString =@"\\*( *[0-9]{1,}.*): (.*)";
NSRegularExpressionOptions options = NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive;
NSError* error = NULL;

NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regexString options:options error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
}

NSArray* results = [regex matchesInString:rawContentString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [rawContentString length])];
for (NSTextCheckingResult* result in results) {

    NSString* resultString = [rawContentString substringWithRange:result.range];
    NSLog(@"%@",resultString);
}
```

unfortunately I think the regex is not working the way I hope and I dont know how to capture the matched date and text.
Any help would be great.
BTW: there is not by any chance a regex Pattern compilation for MediaWiki Syntax out there somewhere ?

Thanks in advance
Heiko
*

Comment: I'd use http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/ if i'd be you. It performs much better in my experience, and usually you get what you need.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. I looked into that. But my app will only be running on 4.0+ so I assumed it would be better to go with the IOS regex funtionality. is that not the case ?

Comment: AFAIK they use the same thing underlying, and regexkit seems a lot nicer to use - but i guess it's personal preference really. But maybe somebody else knows more about that.

Comment: (fyi, I'm the author of RegexKitLite).  Both `NSRegularExpression` and RegexKitLite use the exact same ICU regular expression engine found in `libicucore`.  In theory they should provide identical results, but in practice there may be some extremely minor differences (RegexKitLite must use public API's exclusively, for example, whereas `NSRegularExpression` can use private APIs).  It is my opinion that the difference is, as @LordT said, "personal preference".  Also, at the time of this writing, RegexKitLite will work on nearly all Mac OS X and iOS versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the regex, i think something around these lines:

```
\*([ 0-9]{1,}.*):(.*)
```

should work better to what you need. You're not escaping the first *, and why is there a * in the first group statement?

Comment: Hey, thanks - looks much cleaner :-) as for the * in the first Group: I wanted to prepare for spaces between the '*' and the date.

Comment: that makes sense, but then it would be `[ ]*`, not ` *`

Comment: great :-) I have the same thing in an other regex. so you just solved a couple of problems for me... thanks

Answer (score 3):

My issue was that I was using `matchesInString` and I needed to use `firstMatchInString` because it returns multiple ranges in a single `NSTextCheckingResult`.

This is counter intuitive, but it worked.

I got the answer from http://snipplr.com/view/63340/

**My Code (to parse credit card track data):**

```
NSRegularExpression *track1Pattern = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"%.(.+?)\\^(.+?)\\^([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}).+?\\?." options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

NSTextCheckingResult *result = [track1Pattern firstMatchInString:trackString options:NSMatchingReportCompletion range:NSMakeRange(0, trackString.length)];

self.cardNumber = [trackString substringWithRange: [result rangeAtIndex:1]];
self.cardHolderName = [trackString substringWithRange: [result rangeAtIndex:2]];
self.expirationMonth = [trackString substringWithRange: [result rangeAtIndex:3]];
self.expirationYear = [trackString substringWithRange: [result rangeAtIndex:4]];
```